# IoT Hub / Stream Analytics - SQL - Convert incoming timestamp to Date Time

Tags: sql, azure, azure-iot-hub, stream-analytics

I have a timestamp coming in as milliseconds after 01/01/1970 ([timestamp] below is the column name for the data), and need to add an additional column that uses SQL to take these milliseconds and convert it to a date/time format.

I have attempted:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, [timestamp] %1000, DATEADD(SECOND, [timestamp] /1000, '19700101'))
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot cast value '19700101' of type 'nvarchar(max)' to type
> 'datetime' in expression 'DATEADD ( SECOND , [timestamp] / 1000 ,
> '19700101' )'. At line '2' and column '152'.

Any help is appreciated, thank you! - M

Comment: please specify the date format.

Comment: have to tried to specify 19700101 in ISO timestamp format instead? so "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"?

Comment: @silent what's the timestamp data look like, can you show me one?

Comment: @leon Yue The timestamp data format coming in looks like: 1607040000021. A quick google search shows that it may be called "UNIX Epoch"?

Comment: @Silent I have not tried that yet, unfortunately I am not able to change the data format before it lands in IoT Hub, only able change it by querying it through Stream Analytics.

Comment: I’m not talking about your input data. But about the very last part in your query

Comment: @Silent - it looks like that should work! thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it. I made an answer out of that. please accept that if it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `19700101` in ISO timestamp format instead, so `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`

```
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, [timestamp] %1000, DATEADD(SECOND, [timestamp] /1000, '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'))
```